# Probability that my sheet is black

Tags: probability

Randomly selected one of the three sheets, painted on both sides: black-black, black-and-white and white-white, and then randomly selected one of it's side. If this side is black, what is the probability that the second is also black?

My attempt is:
$C_1$ - one side is black

$C_2$ - second side is black

$BB$ - It was selected white-white

$BC$ - It was selected white-black

$CC$ It was selected black-black

We are searching: $P(C_1|C_2)$

$P(C_1|C_2) = \frac{P(C_1\cap C_2)}{P(C_2)}$

$P(C_2) = P(C_2\cap BC) + P(C_2\cap CC) = \frac13\frac{1}{2}+\frac13 = \frac12$

$P(C_1\cap C_2)= P(C_1\cap C_2\cap BC) + P(C_1\cap C_2\cap CC) = 0 + \frac{1}{3} = \frac13$

Finally:

$P(C_1|C_2) = \frac13\cdot\frac21=\frac23 $

Comment: $P(C_2 \cap BC) = \frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{3}$ because if the card chosen was $BC$, there is another chance of a half that the white side was chosen first...

Comment: Look now and check please.

Comment: Looks OK now. But I think my write-up is cleaner, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(\text{shown side black}) = \frac{1}{3}P(\text{shown side is black }|\text{ card = ww}) + \frac{1}{3}P(\text{shown side is black }|\text{ card = wb}) + \frac{1}{3}P(\text{shown side is black }|\text{ card = bb}) = \frac{1}{3}\cdot 0 + \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot 1 = \frac{1}{2}$

$P(\text{other side black } | \text{ shown side is black}) = \frac{P(\text{other side black and shown side is black})}{P(\text{shown side black})}$ by definition. We already know the denominator, while:

$P(\text{other side black and shown side is black}) = \frac{1}{3}P(\text{other side black and shown side is black } | \text{ card = ww}) + \frac{1}{3}P(\text{other side black and shown side is black } | \text{ card = wb}) + \frac{1}{3}P(\text{other side black and shown side is black } | \text{ card = bb}) = \frac{1}{3}\cdot 0 + \frac{1}{3}\cdot 0 + \frac{1}{3} \cdot 1 = \frac{1}{3}$,

so the required probability is $\frac{1 \over 3}{1 \over 2} = {2 \over 3}$.

**added:** Another way to see this: there are 6 equally likely options:

1. WW chosen, show first white.
2. WW chosen, show second white
3. WB chosen, show white
4. WB chosen, show black
5. BB chosen, show first black
6. BB chosen, show second black.

As we know that black was shown, we are in option 4,5 or 6, and in two of those (5/6) the other side is black as well. So $\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: So, where I made a mistake ?

Comment: I editet my post, look again please